# lxml xslt performance versus xpath and replace

Tags: python, xslt, xpath, lxml

I have some code that, as part of its running, takes a HTML document and mangles it into another form for the sake of output. (HTML to BBCode, essentially.)

I am currently doing this via defining a dictionary of XPath and the replacements, and then iterating over the dictionary with tools from lxml:

```
change_xpaths = {
                  XPath(".//span[contains(@style, 'font')]") : "font",
                  XPath(".//span[contains(@style, 'color')]") : "color",
                  XPath(".//span[contains(@style, 'size')]") : "size"
                  }

replace_xpaths = {
            XPath(".//span[@style='text-decoration: underline']") : "u",
            XPath(".//span[@style='text-decoration: line-through']") : "s",
            XPath(".//div[@style='padding-left: 30px']") : "remove"
                }

def _clean_text(cls, raw):
    for ele in cls.struck_through_xpath(raw):
        ele.getparent().remove(ele)
    for xp, repl in cls.replace_xpaths.items():
        for ele in xp(raw):
            ele.attrib.pop("style")
            ele.tag = repl
    for xp, chng in cls.change_xpaths.items():
        for ele in xp(raw):
            ele.tag = chng
    for br in raw.xpath(".//br"):
        try:
            br.tail = "\n" + br.tail
        except TypeError:
            br.tail = "\n"
    strip_elements(raw, 'img', with_tail = False)
    strip_elements(raw, 'br', with_tail = False)
    strip_tags(raw, 'remove')
```

(This is, indeed, part of a class definition.)

I understand that I can do this using an xslt transform, too.

I would like, firstly, a conformation that I can indeed do all this with xslt, namely, replacing some tags with non-standard tags, and outright removing tags while leaving their text or tail content.

Secondly, I would like to know if I can expect a significant performance increase by doing so? I would suspect so, however, I can't seem to find much about this on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Question 1:* Yes, this is possible with XSLT. But it seems that you simply ignore the font, color and size values. Actually parsing these values from inline CSS could be complicated with XSLT 1.0.

*Question 2:* I think it will be significantly faster. With your current solution, you have to iterate all nodes of your document multiple times (more than 10 times, AFAICS). With an XSLT stylesheet, you visit each input node only once. Also, since lxml is based on libxml2 and libxslt, you'll need less calls into the C API which can be quite expensive in my experience.

OTOH, you could get a similar performance boost by rewriting your Python code to scan the document only once.

Make sure that you compile your XSLT stylesheet only once if you make multiple transformations.

There also some optimizations possible on the XSLT level. The most elegant way would be to write templates like:

```
<xsl:template match="span[contains(@style, 'font')]">...
<xsl:template match="span[contains(@style, 'color')]">...
<xsl:template match="span[contains(@style, 'size')]">...
```

It might be a little faster to have a single template per element name like this:

```
<xsl:template match="span">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(@style, 'font')">...
        <xsl:when test="contains(@style, 'color')">...
        <xsl:when test="contains(@style, 'size')">...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I actually don't quite ignore the color, font and size values; I merely clean them up a bit first with the XPath and later regex substitute them into the desired form of `[color=#123456]`. Additionally, how would I rewrite this so that it goes through the document only once? I'm not really seeing a way apart from some unwieldy state machine.

Comment: Oh. I could iterate through the entire document, and test each node against the dictionaries of tests. Would that be less expensive than testing for each XPath, though?

Comment: Having thought it over, I'm not at all sure that iterating over the document and calling the tests on each node would be less expensive, if calls to C are themselves expensive. I would definitely be calling C functions a lot more that way!